# Can you help identify this weed which sparrows like?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

I live in Ontario, near Toronto and there's this plant which grows as a 'weed' in lawns I'd like to identify.

It usually shows up in lawns or in the cracks between pavements in late summer to autumn.  It forms these fluffy masses, and when mowed acts as a kind of loose ground cover.

It produces tiny seeds that the sparrows like to eat.

The leaves are approx 10-15 mm in length.

[image]

Comment: Some kind of prostrate knotweed, possibly?

Comment: So  Polygonum avicular.  I think you're right @Peter4075.  If you turn that into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As identified in a comment, the plant is [Prostrate knotweed](https://content.ces.ncsu.edu/prostrate-knotweed). It loves to grow in compacted soil, so it's usually found in the grass within 6 inches or so of a sidewalk or driveway, or in any heavily compacted lawn. The taproot is relatively easy to pull after a rain.